# Double anudatta marking using devanagari

Tags: languages

[image]

Can anyone tell me as to how I will produce the above text using the "devanagari" package. My input is the following:

```
{\dn\dnveda tat \|{sa}\_{vi}tur-vare.nya.m |}
```

but I don't get the double `||` mark over the "re" line. How can i produce it?

```
\documentclass{revtex4}
\usepackage{devanagari}
\usepackage[width=4.5in, height=7.0in, top=0.3in, papersize={5.5in,8.5in}]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\title{{\dn \huge || sandhyaa-vandanam ||}}
\author{{\dn \large puurvabhaaga.h}}
\maketitle

\section*{{\dn\dnnum \Large aacamanam || 1 ||}}

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{itemize}
\item{{\dn acyutaaya nama.h |}}
\item{{\dn anantaaya nama.h |}}
\item{{\dn govindaaya nama.h ||}}
\end{itemize}
\vspace*{0.4cm}

{\dn ke"sava| naaraaya.na| maadhava| govinda| vi.s.no| madhusuudana| trivikrama| vaamana| "sriidhara| h.r.siike"sa| padmanaabha| daamodara||}

\section*{{\dn\dnnum \Large ga.napati-dhyaanam || 2 ||}}

\begin{verse}
{\dn "suklaambaradhara.m vi.s.nu.m "sa"sivar.na.m caturbhujam | \\ prasannavadana.m dhyaayet sarva-vighnopa"saantaye||}
\end{verse}

\section*{{\dn\dnnum \Large praa.naayaama.h || 3 ||}}
\begin{verse}
{\dn\dnveda\dnsamaveda o.m bhu.h| o.m bhuva.h| o\@suva.h| o.m maha.h| o.m jana.h| o.m tapa.h| o\@\_{sa}tyam|| \\ o.m tat \|{sa}\_{vi}tu\|{rvare.nya}.m bha\|{rgo} \_{de}va\|{sya} dhimahi| \\ dhi\_{yo} yo \|{na}.h pra\_{co}da\|{yaa}t|| \\ omaa\_{po}-jyo\_{ti}-ra\_{so}.am.r\_{ta.m}-bra\_{hma} bhurbhu\_{va}ssu\_{va}rom||}
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

This is how i typeset using the devanagari package in LaTeX. then i save this as abc.dn file and then run the devnagari preprocessor to get the output.

Comment: Are you using XeTeX? I believed that `devanagari.sty` is for LaTeX.

Comment: @egreg: No, no there was no XeLaTeX tag. So i tagged it xetex

Comment: Please, make a complete minimal example.

Comment: @egre what does that mean

Comment: Please, look at this [meta question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: @egreg but i have added a sample already what is the problem

Comment: No it's not a sample. What document class? What packages? How do you compile that?

Comment: @egreg: Now is it ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is the correct way, but it seems to do what you need:

```
{\dn\dnveda tat \|{sa}\_{vi}tur-va\|{re}\|{\,}\negthinspace.nya.m |}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot. It would be nice if you answer my previous question as well.

Comment: But how do you discover all these :(

Comment: Sorry, but I discovered it by trial and error. The manual calls that symbol a "svarita", but I know *nothing* of Sanskrit and related languages.